# dockerizing django, docker-compose works but not docker run

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a django app (url shortener for k8s) here `[https://github.com/MrAmbiG/shorty/tree/k8s][1]`. The `docker-compose` version works with the same docker image but the `docker run` doesn't work (I cannot access from host, no errors). Docker and docker-compose up both are from docker.io and both are using the same docker image but why the difference?
I apologize for not posting all the contents of the file but rather posting the github url itself.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  django:
    image: gajuambi/shorty
    ports:
      - 80:8001
    env_file:
      - ../.env
```

Below Doesnt work
`docker run --name shorty -it --env-file .env  gajuambi/shorty -p 8001:8001`
The docker image itself runs with no error but when I enter the address in the browser of the host (my windows laptop) and I get nothing.
I tried the following urls in my host where docker is running (laptop) browser
http://localhost:8001/
http://127.0.0.1:8001/
I tried binding the django to the following addresses
0.0.0.0
0
127.0.0.1
but no go.

Comment: Can you please share the error that you are getting while executing the docker run command?

Comment: @PavanYadav updated the question.

Comment: Can you tell me the URL that you using in your browser. If you are using the localhost, please try with laptop ip address with 8001 port

Comment: @PavanYadav updated the question with the suggested information.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve] in the question itself.  A pointer to the GitHub project is sometimes useful, but it's not a substitute for including enough detail in the question to understand what's going on.  It's important to show what's in the Dockerfile (what's the main container `CMD`?) and at least a little detail about the server process it's trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

ports:
- 80:8001

i think your application running on port **80** as you tried binding app on **0.0.0.0** default port will be 80

but you forwarding port **8001** while running the docker command

Please try with

```
docker run --name shorty -it --env-file .env  gajuambi/shorty -p 8001:80
```

Also, try with opening the **IP** of **host machine** (computer) or `**docker bridge IP**`

http://{host IP}:8001

Comment: same result `docker rm shorty -f && 
docker build -t gajuambi/shorty -f .\Deployment\Dockerfile . && docker run --name shorty -it --env-file .env  gajuambi/shorty -p 8001:80`

Answer (score 0):

updated the entrypoint command to
`daphne shorty.asgi:application -b 0 -p 8000`
Currently `docker rm shorty -f &&  docker build -t gajuambi/shorty -f .\Deployment\Dockerfile . && docker run --name shorty -it --env-file .env -p 80:8000 gajuambi/shorty` is working fine.
I have updated the github repo for reference.
`https://github.com/MrAmbiG/shorty.git`